AttributeError: module 'scikit_posthocs' has no attribute 'plot_cd_diagram'
I'm trying to plot the critical difference diagram in Nemenyi post-hoc test using the scikit-learn.
# Step 6: Visualize the Results with Critical Difference Diagram
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sp.plot_cd_diagram(performance_data, labels=models, alpha="0.05", title=f"Critical Difference Diagram ({metric_to_analyze})")
plt.show()

However, I'm encountering the following error:
AttributeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
      1 # Step 6: Visualize the Results with Critical Difference Diagram
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
----> 3 sp.plot_cd_diagram(performance_data, labels=models, alpha="0.05", title=f"Critical Difference Diagram ({metric_to_analyze})")
      4 plt.show()

AttributeError: module 'scikit_posthocs' has no attribute 'plot_cd_diagram'


plot_cd_diagram doesn't exist in https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Maybe it changed its name in recent versions and you need to use sp.critical_difference_diagram()
